# What is the probability that a matrix with i.i.d. normal entries is stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ random matrix, such that the entries $a_{ij}$ are i.i.d. from the standard normal distribution.

I'm curious on the probability that $A$ is Schur stable. That is, $$P(\rho(A) < 1),$$ where $\rho(A)=\max\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in spec(A)\}$.

Are there practical lower bounds (i.e. something other than insanely tiny values)? The best I was able to figure out was $P(\rho(A)<1)=\sum_{j=1}^nP(|\lambda_j(A)|<1)$, where $\lambda_j$ is the $j$th eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: We know the spectral density of [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).

Comment: @user10354138 That only covers symmetric matrices.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $AA^T$ tell me nothing about the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We form the (real symmetric) matrix
$$
B=AA^T\sim\operatorname{Wishart}_n(I_n,n)
$$
so Weyl's inequality $\lvert\lambda_1\rvert\leq\sigma_1$ for $A$ gives
$$
\mathbb{P}(\rho(B)\leq 1)\leq\mathbb{P}(\rho(A)<1).
$$

But we know the spectral density of $B$ is given by
$$
f(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)=c_n\exp(-\tfrac12\sum_i\lambda_i)\prod_i \lambda_i^{-1/2}\prod_{i<j}\lvert\lambda_i-\lambda_j\rvert\quad(\lambda_i>0\forall i)
$$
where the normalisation constant
$$
c_n=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{2^{n^2/2}[\prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma(\frac12(n-i+1))]^2}.
$$
and so the distribution of the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1=\lambda_1(B)$ is given by the CDF
$$
F_{\lambda_1}(x)=\mathbb{P}(\lambda_1\leq x)=c_n\cdot\operatorname{Pf}(M).
$$
where $\operatorname{Pf}(M)$ is the Pffafian of the real skew-symmetric $(2\lceil n/2\rceil)\times(2\lceil n/2\rceil)$ matrix $M$
$$
M_{ij}=\begin{cases}
\int_0^x\int_0^x\operatorname{sgn}(\alpha-\beta) \alpha^{i-\frac32}e^{-\alpha/2}\cdot\beta^{j-\frac32}e^{-\beta/2}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha\,\mathrm{d}\beta & 1\leq i,j\leq n\\
\int_0^x \alpha^{i-\frac32}e^{-\alpha/2}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha&i\leq n,j=n+1\text{ and }2\nmid n\\
-\int_0^x\beta^{j-\frac32}e^{-\beta/2}\,\mathrm{d}\beta&j\leq n,i=n+1\text{ and }2\nmid n\\
0 & i=j=n+1\text{ and }2\nmid n
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Does this imply that $F_{\lambda_1}(x)=0$ when $n$ is odd? Also, do you have any resources that show this line of computation?

Comment: When $n$ is odd you have an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ skew-symmetric matrix $M$, so the Pfaffian is not zero.

Comment: You want to look at de Brujin's [paper](https://research.tue.nl/en/publications/on-some-multiple-integrals-involving-determinants) "On some multiple integrals involving determinants" (1955).

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, that paper seems hard to find on the internet. The link you provided actually has a broken link to the pdf download. Do you have any other resources or textbooks maybe that talk about this stuff?

Comment: One last question. What if the entries of $A$ are Gaussian, but not from the standard Gaussian. I am assuming that changes quite a lot, no?

Comment: I agree.  We probably won't have a nice spectral density to do the computation in the general matrix gaussian case.

Comment: Google's first result gives [this alternative link to the paper](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/1920642/597510.pdf) which is still alive at the moment.